# View gets cut off when returning from a viewcontroller that is in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, orientation

Ok this is my scenario :

My application  has a Tab Bar Controller embedded with a Navigation Controller embedded as well, The first view controller will handle both orientations but the other view controllers won't. So I am sub classing Tab Bar and Navigation Bar to listen for Orientation changes, so whenever there is an orientation change Tab Bar Controller asks its Navigation Controller if it should rotate, etc, and Navigation Controller asks the current view controller for orientation changes managing correctly the orientation. Everything is working fine, the problem I am having now is that whenever my News View Controller (the one that handles both orientation as seen in picture) is in Landscape then if I tap on the Prices tab, it takes me to the Prices View Controller and the view gets cut off. Notice that the orientation is fine, since I only want this view to be in portrait mode, I've been NSLoging like crazy to check if the frame of the view gets re sized but it is still the same yet the view looks like it's been cut off(as seen in picture as well)

[image: News View Controller(Handles both orientations)]
[image: Prices View Controller only in portrait. When News is in portrait then everything looks cool]
[image: News in Landscape all good still]
[image: Why is this happening? I nslog the view frame and it's height is 387, i don't understand]

Any Help I would really appreciate it. I've been dealing with this for 3 days now
Help

Answer (score 0):

try setting the view's autoresizingmask to widthSizeable=YES heightSizeable=YES flexibleMaxX=YES and flexibleMaxY=YES